# Angular dist couldnt be loaded in Teams with node js

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-web-app-service, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

i managed to create an teams app with sso. So i wanted to take this local app to an azure web app. So i started deploy my angular frontend from my node js backend like following:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
  // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

so this works fine when i try this local:
[Fronend local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPL3Q.png)

it even works fine on my azurewebapp! but when i open it up in teams with importing an manifest and try to open the Page it says it refused the connection.

just let me know if u need more infos. Thanks for help!

Comment: is the app running on httpS?

Comment: Yes it is https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for my Problem. I had requiered helemt in my node.js backend. So Helemt sets the X-Frame-Options. After deleting helmet it works fine. I had helmet in my code before importet like this:

```
const helmet = require("helmet");
app.use(helmet());
```

So for now i just delete it and it causes no more errors for displaying my app in teams.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Yes it solved my problem.